# How can I use multiple python virtual environments on same server

Tags: python, virtualenv

How can I deploy and host multiple python  projects with different dependancies on the same server at the same time?

Comment: You've answered your own question. Use `virtualenv`.

Comment: (A virtual environment is basically a copy of Python in a folder that has its own collection of installed packages etc. To set one up you choose a folder somewhere, and run `virtualenv` on it; that will create a Python and a pip executable. Installing packages with that pip will then cause them only to be installed for that particular Python.)

Comment: just create another virtualenv in other path.

Comment: I know how to use virtual environments for development, but just one virtual environment can be activated at the same time (by doing source sitename/bin/activate). How can I run multiple of those at the same time?

Comment: It might help if you expanded on your intended workflow. Of course two terminal sessions can have different virtualenvs but it's hard to understand why you'd want the same process to run multiple virtualenvs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not true of course that only one virtualenv can be activated at once. Yes, only one can be active in a shell session at once, but your sites are not deployed via shell sessions. Each WSGI process, for example, will create its own environment: so all you need to do is to ensure that each wsgi script activates the correct virtualenv, as is (in the case of mod_wsgi at least) [well documented](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments).

Answer (score 1):

Use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for python. You can can install any other version of python/packages in it, if required.